# Create Alarm or Reminder in Windows Phone 8.1 C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, backgroundworker, windows-phone-8.1

How I can Use Reminder or Alarm in Windows Phone 8.1(Universal Apps) in Universal Project

in windows phone 8 ,you can added reminder by using  **Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler** Namespace

```
        Reminder reminder = new Reminder("myreminder")
        {
            Title = " app reminder",
            Content = "Reminder !",
            BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
            RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.Daily,
            ExpirationTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30),
            NavigationUri = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)


        };
        ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

But how I can use it in windows phone 8.1 or provide me another way to do it in windows phone 8.1.

as you know the alarm or reminder working in background even if the app closed .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 Store / XAML apps, the api for Reminders and Alarms is not accessible for the 3rd party devs.

[`WP8.1 - No Alarms & Reminders`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68b50bbb-3296-46be-a85f-669caecedd19/wp81-no-alarms-reminders-whats-the-alternative?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Any idea if Win10 will have something for us in this regard?